# Multi-column insert algorithm for a virtual "table"?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a JavaScript "table" made out of an Array with "rows" made out Objects sharing a similar structure (member properties being similar to form "columns" with their values as "cells").

The table has been sorted with one or more columns in a cascading fashion via mergesort's applied in reverse order and can be anywhere from 20 - 20,000 rows long.

What is the best algorithm to use for inserting a new row into the table at the correct location without re-sorting the entire table (or rather, **to find the insertion-index for the new row**)?

An example of this would be:

```
Sort Order = name, id

id    name    description
0     a       blah
1     b       foo
2     d       blah
3     d       blah 2
...
19    d       blah 18

Insert:

id    name    description
20    c       bar

To Yield:

id    name    description
0     a       blah
1     b       foo
20    c       bar
2     d       blah
3     d       blah 2
...
19    d       blah 18
```

(sorry for all the quoted definitions, when I attempted to ask this question the first time there appeared to be a great deal of confusion from people believing "table" referred to a SQL-database table or similar)

Comment: i would use a binary search

Comment: @dave and that's the right answer, except that for a multi-key sort one must repeat the binary search for each key until you find an empty slot for the new record (a sort column that has no duplicates for the value in the new record) or you run out of key columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this as follows for anyone that is interested:

```
var table = [
    {i: 0, id: 0, id2: 0, id3: 0},
    {i: 1, id: 0, id2: 1, id3: 0},
    {i: 2, id: 1, id2: 0, id3: 0},
    {i: 3, id: 1, id2: 2, id3: 0},
    {i: 4, id: 1, id2: 3, id3: 0},
    {i: 5, id: 2, id2: 0, id3: 1},
    {i: 6, id: 2, id2: 0, id3: 2},
    {i: 7, id: 2, id2: 1, id3: 0},
    {i: 8, id: 2, id2: 1, id3: 1},
    {i: 9, id: 2, id2: 2, id3: 0}
    ];

var sort = ['id', 'id2'];

function InsertionIndex(table, sort, row) {
    var state = {
        _compare: function (left, right) {
            if (left < right) { return (1); }
            else if (left > right) { return (-1); }
            return (0);
        },
        column: '',
        max: table.length,
        min: 0,
        row: row,
        _search: function (state) {
            var minc = this._compare(this.table[this.min][this.column], state.row[this.column]);
            var maxc = this._compare(this.table[this.max - 1][this.column], this.row[this.column]);
            if (state.table[state.min][state.column] == state.table[state.max - 1][state.column]) { return; }
            if (minc < 0) { state.max = state.min; return; }
            if (maxc > 0) { state.min = state.max; return; }
            if ((state.max - state.min) > 2) {
                var mid = Math.ceil((state.min + state.max) / 2);
                var midc = state._compare(state.table[mid][state.column], state.row[state.column]);
                if (midc < 0) {
                    state.max = mid;
                    state._search(state);
                    return;
                } else if (midc > 0) {
                    state.min = mid;
                    state._search(state);
                    return;
                } else {
                    for (var i = mid - 1; i >= state.min; i--) { if (state._compare(state.table[i][state.column], state.row[state.column]) != 0) { state.min = i + 1; break; } }
                    for (var i = mid + 1; i < state.max; i++) { if (state._compare(state.table[i][state.column], state.row[state.column]) != 0) { state.max = i; break; } }
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                if (maxc < 0) {
                    if (minc > 0) { state.min = state.max - 1; state.max = state.max - 1; return; }
                    else { state.max = state.max - 1; return; }
                } else if (minc > 0) {
                    state.min = state.max - 1; return;
                }
            }
            return;
        },
        table: table
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < sort.length; i++) {
        state.column = sort[i];
        state._search(state);
        if (state.min >= state.max) { break; }
    }
    return ({ max: state.max, min: state.min });
}

for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
    document.write(table[i].i + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + table[i].id+ '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + table[i].id2 + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + table[i].id3 + '<BR />');
}
var insertion = {i: 3, id: 0, id2: 1, id3: 1};
document.write(InsertionIndex(table, sort, insertion).min + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + InsertionIndex(table, sort, insertion).max + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2<BR />');
insertion = {i: 3, id: 1, id2: 1, id3: 1};
document.write(InsertionIndex(table, sort, insertion).min + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + InsertionIndex(table, sort, insertion).max + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3<BR />');
insertion = {i: 3, id: 2, id2: 1, id3: 1};
document.write(InsertionIndex(table, sort, insertion).min + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + InsertionIndex(table, sort, insertion).max + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;7&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;9<BR />');
insertion = {i: 3, id: 3, id2: 1, id3: 1};
document.write(InsertionIndex(table, sort, insertion).min + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + InsertionIndex(table, sort, insertion).max + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10<BR />');
```